# The whole SE is now a programming community?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange.com

The header at https://stackexchange.com/about says:

> [image]

Did the whole Stack Exchange suddenly become a programming community?

Comment: *"Did the whole Stack Exchange suddenly become a programming community?"* And, if not... [tag:feature-request]? 8-)

Comment: Well, they mean Stack Overflow has evolved into whole network of sites and probably did not find better way to sum it up in one short sentence. Won't call it a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the text in the page explains the title:

> Stack Exchange is a network of 130+ Q&A communities **including Stack Overflow, the preeminent site for programmers to find, ask, and answer questions about software development.**

(emphasis mine)

The fact is that the programming community has grown, *to include other Q&A sites that are not programming related*. The page shows a timeline how SE has evolved from SO to the trilogy (SO,SU,SF) to the Q&A community it is now.

Comment: Yes, "including SO". So what? And the last sentence sounds a big strange. SO is not going to include other QA sites

Comment: No, SE is. This is just a piece of history. The original SE community *is* growing.

Comment: The further it gets from StackOverflow's humble origins, the harder it becomes to argue that StackExchange = StackOverflow + o(t).

Comment: From the history perspective it is right. Once it was just a programming community. This of course isn't true any more, but still it is part of the SE history.